# How to authenticate with Azure AD / OpenId but use Entity Framework based user/role data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect

I'm trying to improve the authentication story for a legacy ASPNet MVC/OWIN app - Currently, it uses the AspNetUsers / AspNetRoles / claims etc tables along with forms + cookie based authentication.

I want to use Azure AD / OpenID Connect for authentication but then load the user profile/roles from the database as currently. Basically, no more password management within the app. Users themselves will still need to exist/be created within the app.

The application is quite dependent on some custom data associated with these users so simply using the roles from Active Directory isn't an option.

The OpenID auth works, however I'm not sure how to use the existing Identityuser / IdentityUserRole / RoleManager plumbing in conjunction with it.

Basically once the user authenticates with Open ID we'll want to load the corresponding user from the database (matching on email address) and use that user profile / roles going forward.

In particular, the AuthorizeAttribute (with specific roles specified) should continue to function as before.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppIdentityDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures OpenIDConnect Authentication & Adds Custom Application Authorization Logic on User Login.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The application represented by a <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> object.</param>
    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        //Configure OpenIDConnect, register callbacks for OpenIDConnect Notifications
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigHelper.AadInstance,
                    ConfigHelper.Tenant), // For Single-Tenant
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigHelper.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/OtherError?errorDescription=" +
                                                  context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        string userIdentityName = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name;
                        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
                        var user = userManager.FindByEmail(userIdentityName);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            Log.Error("User {name} authenticated with open ID, but unable to find matching user in store", userIdentityName);
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Error/NoAccess?identity=" + userIdentityName);
                            return;
                        }

                        user.DateLastLogin = DateTime.Now;
                        IdentityResult result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                        if (result.Succeeded)
                        {
                            var authManager = context.OwinContext.Authentication;
                            ClaimsIdentity ident = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);


                            // Attach additional claims from DB user
                            authManager.User.AddIdentity(ident);

                            // authManager.SignOut();
                            // authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

                            return;
                        }

                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to update user {0} after log-in", userIdentityName));
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am stuck in similar situation. How did you register the Azure Ad user into the database server during the first time? Did you register with dummy password or used CreateIdentityAsync with external bearer?

Comment: I'm calling `UserManager.CreateAsync(user)`, passing in the details of the new user (first name, last name, email etc - no password). In the constructor for my `AppUserManager` I'm assigning a custom `UserValidator` instance with the options `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false` & `RequireUniqueEmail = true`. HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AppIdentityDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures OpenIDConnect Authentication & Adds Custom Application Authorization Logic on User Login.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The application represented by a <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> object.</param>
    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieDomain = ConfigHelper.AuthCookieDomain,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
        });

        //Configure OpenIDConnect, register callbacks for OpenIDConnect Notifications
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigHelper.AadInstance, ConfigHelper.Tenant),

                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/OtherError?errorDescription=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        // Set the post-logout & redirect URI dynamically depending on the incoming request.
                        // That allows us to use the same Azure AD app for two subdomains (these two domains give different app behaviour)
                        var builder = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Uri);
                        builder.Fragment = builder.Path = builder.Query = "";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        app.Use<EnrichIdentityWithAppUserClaims>();
    }
}

public class EnrichIdentityWithAppUserClaims : OwinMiddleware
{
    public EnrichIdentityWithAppUserClaims(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await MaybeEnrichIdentity(context);
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private async Task MaybeEnrichIdentity(IOwinContext context)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity openIdUserIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Authentication.User.Identity;
        string userIdentityName = openIdUserIdentity.Name;

        var userManager = context.GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
        var appUser = userManager.FindByEmail(userIdentityName);

        if (appUser == null)
        {
            Log.Error("User {name} authenticated with open ID, but unable to find matching user in store", userIdentityName);
            return;
        }

        appUser.DateLastLogin = DateTime.Now;
        IdentityResult result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity appUserIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(appUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
            openIdUserIdentity.AddClaims(appUserIdentity.Claims);
        }
    }
}
```

It's quite similar to what I had originally - (note: `RoleClaimType = ClaimTypesRoles` not "roles") except instead of trying to deal with the user in the `SecurityTokenValidated` callback, I've added some custom middleware that finds a matching user (by email address) and adds the claims (app roles) from the matching app user to the authenticated user identity (OpenID identity).

Finally, I protected all controller actions with a (custom) `AuthorizeAttribute` (not shown here) that ensures the authenticated user at least belongs to the "User" role (if not, redirects them to a "no access" page indicating that we've authenticated them but they have no access in the system).

Answer (score 0):

> The OpenID auth works, however I'm not sure how to use the existing Identityuser / IdentityUserRole / RoleManager plumbing in conjunction with it.
>
> The application is quite dependent on some custom data associated with these users so simply using the roles from Active Directory isn't an option.

For your requirement, I assume that you could build your identity server (e.g. [IdentityServer3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/)) and leverage [IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity) for identity management using ASP.NET Identity.

For your web client application, you could use OpenID Connect middleware and set Authority to your custom identity server and set your pre-configured ClientId on your identity server.

Moreover, you could follow this [tutorial](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) for quickly getting started with IdentityServer3 and the full samples [IdentityServer3 Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples).